# Django search form autocomplete

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a code that queries multiple database tables.

```
def search_view(request):
    models = [Item, Category, SubCategory]
    template_name = 'home-page.html'
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    print('query: {}'.format(len(query)))
    if len(query):
        item_items = models[0].objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains = query) |
            Q(item_code__icontains = query) |
            Q(description__icontains = query)
        )
        category_items = models[1].objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains = query)
        )
        subcategory_items = models[2].objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains = query)
        )
        return render(request, template_name, context={'item_items': item_items, 'category_items': category_items, 'subcategory_items': subcategory_items, 'query': query})

    return redirect('/')
```

But I want to make autocomplete when I type in the search box.
I tried to do it through `djando-autocomplete-light` but couldn't implement it in my code.
So, maybe someone can help with this.

Comment: This can be done using Javascript as autocomplete works in template. See [this](https://medium.com/@ninajlu/django-ajax-jquery-search-autocomplete-d4b4bf6494dd) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, the article helped a lot!